# Magento 2 - Change format of authentication-popup.html

Tags: magento2, php, login, html, modal-popup

I overridden authentication popup of Magento 2 in my custom theme. I discovered that the file that is called for the popup is with the extension .html (authentication-popup.html). This way I can't add php code.

Can I change the format of "authentication-popup.html" to "authentication-popup.phtml"? How?

Thanks

Comment: No, you can't. You can pass all data through js. Check how knockout js works

Comment: Ok, but with knockout.js can i get form of register.phtml and call him into authentication-popup.html?